# Grid view View pager search not working

Tags: android, search, android-viewpager, android-gridview

I am developing an application which uses View Pager and in view pager fragments and then a grid view.
I have main activity which has search bar and now I want to search from grid view pages. I have implemented searching in fragment but when I search it populates grid with more data.
    In my Adapter I have a method for searching data is,

```
 public void filterData(String query) {

            query = query.toLowerCase();
            // Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(this.tempMenulist.size()),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.mArrayList.clear();

            if (query.isEmpty()) {
                this.mArrayList.addAll(this.mArrayList_temp);

            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < this.mArrayList_temp.size(); i++) {
                    GridItem next = this.mArrayList_temp.get(i);

                    String strFirstName = next.getItem_name().toLowerCase();
                    //String strLastName = next.get("LastName").toLowerCase();
                    //String strFinalName = strFirstName;
                            //+" "+strLastName;
                    if (next.getItem_name().toLowerCase().contains(query)
                            || next.getItem_price().toLowerCase().contains(query) 
                            //|| strFinalName.contains(query)
                            /*|| next.get("attendant").toLowerCase().contains(query)
                            || next.get("order_total").toLowerCase().contains(query)
                            || next.get("appointment_date").toLowerCase().contains(query)*/

                            ) {
                        this.mArrayList.add(next);
                        //Log.d("System Out", "mArrayList in search : "+mArrayList.toString());

                    } else {

                    }

                }
                for (int j = 0; j < mArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    GridItem next1 = this.mArrayList_temp.get(j);

                }
            }
            // Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(this.tempMenulist.size()),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

In Fragment I called  above method on textchange of editext, edittext is in Activity,

```
 EditText etno_searchbar_products  =     (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etno_searchbar_products);
etno_searchbar_products.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                gridImageAdapter.filterData(s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: can you post some code you tried??

Comment: Hi, I have added code that I have tried.